# How do i run a procedure on an onclick event with Dynamically created buttons, and pass variables through

Tags: delphi, button, dynamic

This is in Delphi Pascal

I have dynamical created a 2d array of buttons. I want it such that when you click these buttons, the button pressed will dissapear. (This is to make a minesweeper style game).

Currently i have this array of these buttons, and am trying to set the onclick event to a procedure and passing in the x and y indexes of this button to the procedure such that it can hide the correct button.

Here is what i am using to link to the procedure:
`buttons[x,y].OnClick := buttonClicked(x,y);`

The x and y are made from a for loop, in order that i can have a 2d array.

An this is the error I am getting.

`E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'`

Here is the Procedure:

```
procedure TMainPage.buttonClicked(buttonx: Integer; buttony: Integer);
begin
   buttons[buttonx,buttony].Visible:=False;
end;
```

Im assuming that the problem is that you cannot send variables through on the OnClick event.
I am unsure of a way to do what i want, so guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What the E2010 is telling you is that `buttonClicked` needs to be a method of an object, not a stand-alone procedure and have the same method signature as an `OnClick` handler, otherwise they are not assignment compatible.  If you don't know these concepts, you have some reading to do.

Answer (score 6):

> Currently i have this array of these buttons, and am trying to set the onclick event to a procedure and passing in the x and y indexes of this button to the procedure such that it can hide the correct button.

You will not be able to pass that information *directly* to the `OnClick` event handler using input parameters.  The event is declared as a [`TNotifyEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent), so the only input parameter it can accept is a `TObject` for the object that triggers the event.

However, that object is the clicked `TButton` itself, so you can simply use it as-is:

```
procedure TMainPage.buttonClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TButton(Sender).Visible := False;
end;
```

If, for some reason, you actually needed the XY indexes within the array, you would have to pass those values to the event handler *indirectly*, such as with the button's `Tag` property:

```
buttons[x,y].Tag := Integer(SmallPoint(x, y));

...

procedure TMainPage.buttonClicked(Sender: TObject);
var
  pt: TSmallPoint;
begin
  pt := TSmallPoint(TButton(Sender).Tag);
  // use pt.x and pt.y as needed...
end;
```

Though, a safer option would be to just derive a new class from `TButton` instead, and then you can add whatever you want to it:

```
type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  public
    ArrayX, ArrayY: Integer;
  end;

...

buttons[x,y] := TMyButton.Create(...);
buttons[x,y].ArrayX := x;
buttons[x,y].ArrayY := y;

...

procedure TMainPage.buttonClicked(Sender: TObject);
var
  Btn: TMyButton;
begin
  Btn := TMyButton(Sender);
  // use Btn.ArrayX and Btn.ArrayY as needed...
end;
```

Comment: I think  you should add a reference to [TNotifyEvent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TNotifyEvent.html) as it gives TButton OnClick As an Example

Answer (score 0):

As Remy pointed out, there's a simpler way to have the button be made not visible.

To set the OnClick event when creating each new button, use the following:

```
buttons[x,y].OnClick := @buttonClicked;
```